# Writing query results into a file

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I've problem when I write the result of a query into a file.

```
string file = @"C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\plik.pdk";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

string connection = "DSN=PervasiveData;Database=BAZA1";
string query1 = "SELECT skrot FROM KONTRAHENCI WHERE id = 32";

OdbcConnection MyConn = new OdbcConnection(connection);
OdbcCommand MyCommand = new OdbcCommand(query1, MyConn);
```

And now I must write to file my result of query.

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean the 'solution' of query.. you mean the result ?

Comment: In order to receive an answer, you should show what you have tried and - more importantly - that you have tried something at all. What is the actual question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: laczenie = connection ? zapytanie = query1 ??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. laczenie is connection and zapytanie is query1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up everything:

```
string file = @"C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\plik.pdk";
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(file, true)) {

     string connection = "DSN=PervasiveData;Database=BAZA1";
     string query1 = "SELECT skrot FROM KONTRAHENCI WHERE id = 32";

     OdbcConnection MyConn = new OdbcConnection(connection);

     MyConn.Open();

     OdbcCommand myCommand = new OdbcCommand(query1, myConn);

     var result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

     //Execute command and write output to file
     if((result !=null) && (result != DBNull.Value))
          outputFile.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Always use the "using" directive with Streams to ensure automatic release of the ressource

```
string file = @"C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\plik.pdk";
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(file, true)) {

    string connection = "DSN=PervasiveData;Database=BAZA1";
    string query1 = "SELECT skrot FROM KONTRAHENCI WHERE id = 32";
    OdbcCommand myCommand = new OdbcCommand(query1, myConn);

    //Execute command and write output to file
    outputFile.WriteLine(myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
```

You will need an active connection (myconn) for this in order to work (depends if you use ms sql server oracle etc). You should use the "using" here as well. A simple solution for oracle would be:

```
string yourConnectionString = "DSN=PervasiveData;Database=BAZA1"; // something similar

using (var conn = new OracleConnection(yourConnectionString )) {
   conn.open()
   var myCommand= conn.CreateCommand();
   myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT skrot FROM KONTRAHENCI WHERE id = 32";

   string file = @"C:\Users\jakub\Desktop\plik.pdk";
   using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(file, true)) {
      //Execute command and write output to file
      outputFile.WriteLine(myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
  }
```

Comment: btw. `skrot` (=shortname, shorthand) and `kontrahenci` (contrahents) strongly suggest that this will be textual results, no binary data, so your answer should be OK. I don't know how about unicode or codepage handling though.

Comment: Yeah SO answers will just give you a hint in the right direction. You will have to extend / alter the code for your desire. If this answer solves your problem pklease mark it as the answer so others will find it as well

Comment: But I'm trying to do like you, and program give me error: "Element ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection (Connection). The current connection status: closed"

Comment: you probably have to do something like `MyConn.Open();` before executing command.

Comment: I also suggest to check `ExecuteScalar()` to result a not `null` value or you will get an exception if the query return no results.

Comment: absolutely correct, please add Exception Handling yourself (returning null, connection to db etc). Yes, you should make a connection and open it (that depends which type of connection you will use). I will add this to my answer